# No integer $x$ such that $(x-y)^3+ x^3 = (x+y)^3$

Tags: diophantine-equations

It seems there is no integer $x$ such that such that $(x-y)^3+ x^3 = (x+y)^3$ where $y$ is a non-zero integer.  At least I can't find one.

Am I right and if so, how can one show it?

Comment: It has been known since at least the time of Euler that the equation $a^3+b^3=c^3$ has no non-trivial integer solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only a finite number of possible values of $t = y/x$, just compute them and see they are irrational.   No number theory required, and the same method works in fields where Fermat(3) might be false.

$(1-t)^3 + 1 = (1+t)^3$

$2t^3 + 6t^2 - 1 = 0$.

$T^3 + 6T^2 - 4 = 0$  for $T = 2t$.

There are no integer roots.

Comment: We would want *rational* roots here, not just integer since you've taken a ratio of $x$ and $y$. However in this case, the rational root theorem says that the only rational roots can be $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 4$.

Comment: Yes.  But we have a monic polynomial so its rational roots must be integers.  As specified in the first sentence, we are computing all possible complex values of $t$ and checking that they are irrational.

Comment: Quite right. I was just editing my comment as you said that. I like this answer a lot too. $+1$

Answer (score 10):

We can divide by the cubes of all eventual common factors of $x$ and $y$, so w.l.o.g. $\gcd(x,y)=1$. Expanding all those cubes and rearranging gives
$$
x^3=2y^3+6x^2y.
$$
The right hand side is always even, so the left hand side must be also. Therefore $x$ is even. But then the left hand side is divisible by $8$ as is the term $6x^2y$. This implies that $2y^3$ must also be divisible by $8$ forcing $y$ to be even, too. So $2\mid \gcd(x,y)$ contradicting our assumption.

Comment: You hit this before I did.

Comment: Beautiful argument. $+1$

Comment: This is a line intersected with a Fermat curve, so of course there must be a local argument (because it's simpler than the Fermat curve).  But we can also just calculate all the points of intersection.

Answer (score 4):

A solution would be a special case of Fermat's last therorem, so there are none.

Comment: Is there an elementary proof for this special case? I feel there might be. For example, I think one can show that for any solution both $x$ and $y$ must be even which might be a start.

Comment: I only know that the case $n=3$ was solved long before the theorem was solved. If I remember right, already Euler solved this case.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite as $$ (x+y)^3 - (x-y)^3 = 2 y (3 x^2 + y^2) = x^3$$
In particular, any prime factor of $y$ divides $x$.  But if there
is a solution, there is a minimal one...

Comment: Alternatively observe that the original equation (and indeed the derived equation) is homogeneous of degree $3$ - so any common divisor can be cancelled and $x$ and $y$ can be assumed to be coprime.

Answer (score 1):

Reducing the equation mod $2$ gives

$$x-y+x\equiv x+y\mod2$$

which implies $x\equiv0$ mod $2$.  As noted in Jyrki Lahtonen's answer, we can assume $\gcd(x,y)=1$ (i.e., you can remove any common factor in a solution and still have a solution), hence we can assume $y\equiv1$ mod $2$.  In particular, $x-y$ and $x+y$ are both odd.  But now, reducing things mod $8$ (with the knowledge that $a^3\equiv a$ mod $8$ when $a$ is odd), we have

$$x-y+0\equiv x+y\mod 8$$

which implies $2y\equiv0$ mod $8$, a contradiction to $y\equiv1$ mod $2$.

**Remark**: This approach works if the cube is replaced with *any* odd exponent greater than $1$, e.g., $(x-y)^{23}+x^{23}=(x+y)^{23}$.

Answer (score 0):

working it out you get to:

$$x = \left(2+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{243-27\sqrt{17}}+\sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{17}}\right)y $$

you will notice that what's inside the brackets is non-integer so the question becomes; is there any integer y for which x is an integer. written another way; can the expression within the brackets be written as a fraction of two integers? i.e is the expression rational

$$\frac{x}{y} = \left(2+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt[3]{243-27\sqrt{17}}+\sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{17}}\right) $$

which i think boils down to weather:

$$    \sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{17}}+\sqrt[3]{9-\sqrt{17}} $$

is rational and that i don't know how to prove but ill think about it

Comment: It would be much better to typeset your equations using mathjax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference